# Stored Procedure show the same value for each of the rows

Tags: sql-server

I am having problem where one particular column shows the same value for all the rows. For example, I would like to check which person in charge of what item. How can I do that ?

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I managed to retrieve the two location however the `officername` is the same for all rows.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchDevice]
    @DeviceID AS INT,
    @DeviceImei AS VARCHAR(50),
    @StationID AS INT,
    @ID AS INT,
    @OfficerName AS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        D.imei, L.*, L1.*
    FROM 
        Device D
    INNER JOIN 
        Box on Box.DeviceID = D.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Station on Box.StationID = Station.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Officer on Officer.StationID = Station.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        Role on Role.ID = Officer.RoleID
    INNER JOIN 
        Division on Officer.DivisionID = Division.ID
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 * 
         FROM dbo.Location L1
         WHERE L1.DeviceImei = D.Imei
         GROUP BY DeviceImei, Latitude, Longitude, Distance, LocationSend
         ORDER BY (LocationSend) DESC) AS L
    OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT TOP 1 
             L6.StationID AS 'Station', L3.Name, L5.Id AS 'BoxID', 
             L6.Username AS 'Name', L3.ID AS 'DivisionID'
         FROM 
             [dbo].[Division] L3, dbo.Station L4, dbo.Box L5, dbo.Officer L6,dbo.Role L7
         WHERE 
             L.Latitude IS NOT NULL 
             AND L.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
             AND L.Distance IS NOT NULL 
             AND L.DeviceImei = D.ImeI 
             AND D.ID = L5.DeviceID 
             AND L4.ID = L5.StationID 
             AND L3.ID = L4.[EDivisionID ]  
             AND L4.ID = L6.StationID 
             AND L3.ID = L6.DivisionID
         GROUP BY 
             l6.StationID, L3.Name, L5.Id, L6.Username, L3.ID) AS L1
WHERE
    D.ID = Box.DeviceID 
    AND Officer.StationID = Station.ID 
    AND Officer.RoleID = Role.ID 
    AND Officer.DivisionID = ElectoralDivision.ID 
    AND D.ID = @DeviceID 
     OR L.DeviceImei = @DeviceImei 
     OR L1.Station = @StationID 
     OR L1.DivisionID = @DivisionID 
     OR L1.OfficerName = @OfficerName
END
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your quesion, but I suggest having a read of https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins & https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 (why are you mixing ANSI-89 ANS ANSI 92 join syntax? Some of your aliases are fine too, but then you have L1-L7 and they are all completely different onjects (which is in the same query as the old join syntax).)

Comment: As for your question, we can't run your SQL. We need sample data to sand expected results to be able to really help you here.

Comment: TOP 1 after GROUP BY with no aggregations? TOP 1 without ORDER BY? Bunch of ORs with no parenthesis? Mix of old-school and modern joins, defined column lists and `*`

Comment: Are you saying you expect the officer name to be different? If so there is an issue with your query (clearly there are already many other issues) but we won't be able to help